# Setting up an asymmetric frustum

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d

I have a program in which I am tracking user's position and setting the frustum (setting the camera at user's position) to change the perspective of the scene as per the user's position. Until right now, I had all four corners of the display screen at the same z and I was able to set the asymmetric frustum and change the scene according to the user's perspective.

The current code looks something like the following:

```
UserCam::begin(){
    saveGlobalMatrices();  
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
        glFrustum(_topLeftNear.x, _bottomRightNear.x, _bottomRightNear.y, _topLeftNear.y, _camZNear, _camZFar);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt(_wcUserHead.x, _wcUserHead.y, _topLeftScreen.z, _wcUserHead.x, _wcUserHead.y, _topLeftScreen.z-1, 0, 1, 0);
}

UserCam::end(){
loadGlobalMatrices();
}

UserCam::setupCam(){
    this->_topLeftScreen = _wcTopLeftScreen - _wcUserHead; //wcTopLeftScreen, wcBottomRightScreen and wcUserHead are in the same frame of reference
    this->_bottomRightScreen = _wcBottomRightScreen - _wcUserHead;

    this->_topLeftNear = (_topLeftScreen/ _topLeftScreen.z) * _camZNear;
    this->_bottomRightNear = (_bottomRightScreen/_bottomRightScreen.z )) * _camZNear;
}
```

However, I want to be able to do the same with a display which is kept tilted to the user and/or does not have all its vertices at the same `Z`.

[image]
The above can be imagined as a sort of tilted window, the vertices of which would have the frustum defined from the user's position. How is such a frustum possible where the display does not have all the vertices at the same `Z`?

**EDIT**
There are three planes in the setup that I am considering. The middle one give the correct asymmetric frustum since all the vertices are at the same Z, whereas the left and right planes have two vertices each at different Z. The vertices of the same are as follows:

```
Plane1: TL : (-426.66, 0, 200), TR: (0, 0, 0), BL : (-426.66, 320.79, 200), BR : (0, 320.79, 0)
Plane2: TL : (0, 0, 0), TR: (426.66, 0, 0), BL : (0, 320.79, 0), BR: (426.66, 320.79, 0)
Plane3: TL:  (426.66, 0, 0), TR: (853.32, 0, 200), BL : (426.66, 320.79, 0), BR : (853.32, 320.79, 200)
```

Comment: I think you need a 4th dimension to do that sanely.

Answer (score 7):

The idea in this setup is to transform it to a case where all corners have the same z-coordinate. Usually this is done with a view matrix and you get:

```
overall_transform = (projection) * (view * world)
```

or in the OpenGL wording

```
overall_transform = projection * modelview
```

If you don't want to tamper with the original modelview matrix, you should introduce another matrix in between:

```
overall_transform = (projection * adaption) * (view * world)
```

where `adaption` is a rotation matrix that maps the screen's corners to a plane with constant z-coordinate.

In order to find the correct parameters for `projection` you have to transform the screen with `adaption`.

### Edit

We start with an arbitrary scene where the camera's position, direction and the screen is known. We consider that the model matrices are already there for each object:

[image: Initial situation]

We then need the view transformation `V` that aligns the camera with the origin. This matrix can easily calculated with `gluLookAt`. The overall matrix is then `T = V * M`:

[image: After view transformation]

Up to this step the matrices are the same for all three screens. So this part should be in the modelview matrix. What we add now goes into the projection matrix because it differs per screen.

We need to apply a rotation `R` that aligns the screen perpendicular to the z-axis. The position of the camera must not change at this step because it represents the projection center. The overall transformation is now `T = R * V * M`.

In order to calculate the angle, we can use e.g. `atan2`:

```
dx = right.x - left.x
dz = right.z - left.z
angle = atan2(dz, dx)
```

It might be necessary to adapt this calculation slightly to your actual needs.

[image: After rotation adaption]

Now is the time to apply the actual perspective transform, which can be done with `glFrustum`.

We need to find the local edges of the screen. You could transform the screen coordinates with the current transform (`R * V`).

```
TL' = R * V * TL
BL' = R * V * BL
BR' = R * V * BR
```

Now all three coordinates should have the same z-coordinate. We can use these as follows:

```
common_z = TL'.z = BL'.z = BR'.z
glFrustum(TL'.x / common_z * z_near,
          BR'.x / common_z * z_near,
          BL'.y / common_z * z_near,
          TL'.y / common_z * z_near,
          z_near, z_far)
```

So overall `T = glFrustum * R * V * M`:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(...);
//any further model transforms

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glFrustum(...);
glRotate(...);
```

Comment: So, does this mean I can create a projection matrix with `glFrustum` first assuming same `z` for all four vertices initially, and later multiply the prev. output with an appropriate adaption matrix (which would have translation, rotation transformations as per orientation of my display etc.) to transform the projection as it is in the real world. If the above thing I said is correct, is there a preference as to what same `Z` value should be kept initially for calculating the projection matrix?

Comment: Multiplication with MV matrix works for me to bring the user prependicular to the plane but trying to do so with the projection matrix is giving weird output. Added the information about the vertices of the planes in the post above. The ones with the different Z vertices are on the left and right. And yes, the planes are rectangular and for the current purpose, the rotation can be considered to be happening only around Y axis.

Comment: That's a brilliant brilliant explanation and I understood the the part of doing the rotation of the projection plane with `glRotate` in the projection matrix. If I rotate the camera with such a rotation, I do a post-multiplication with `glRotate` call after `gluLookAt`. However, in the above code of yours `glRotate` still remains after `glFrustum` call which ideally should have been pre-multiplied. I tried the pre-multiplication part as described here http://bit.ly/12EZvKR but still wasn't getting the same results as I got when I did the `glRotate` with the view matrix.

Comment: Also, I wanted to understand as to why there's no rotation pivot needed for projection plane. What I did in my ModelView matrix to achieve the rotation of the camera prependicular to screen was to set a pivot to a particular side I wanted to rotate from using `glTranslate(pivtoSide); glRotate(angle, 0,1,0); glTranslate(-pivotSide);`. As opposed to this, why don't we need to rotate the projection plane at some pivot side?

Comment: @user1240679 You don't need a pivot, because the camera your rotating about is already at the origin. There is no reason why projection matrix order should be inverted. Rotating the alredy projected scene makes no sense in this case.

Comment: But in that case, I shouldn't have been translating to pivot, rotate and then translate back when I was doing the operation inside my ModelView matrix which was giving me the correct result. Here's a quick and dirty code from the app I am testing the code with - http://pastebin.com/2HgADJUR . Notice that rotation I am doing has the pivot to the side from where I try to rotate. If I remove the translate from the center, it does rotate from the centre but then there are other planes as well with which the image the should be stiched as you would notice in the code in the link.